# await y async reemplaza a las promesas?

Tags: javascript, promesas, async-await

En el siguiente codigo funciona `async` y await, mi duda es que si uso async ya no es necesario usar promesas?

```js
async function getMain() {
  var film = 'hola mundo'
    console.log(film);
  return film
};

getMain().then(function(x){console.log(x,'hola')});
```

Answer (score 7):

> Respondiendo a tu primer pregunta, no `async` y `await` no reemplazan a
>   las `promises`, de hecho pueden coexistir las dos en un mismo escenario;
>   por debajo `async` y `await` manejan promesas para resolver los estados

Por otro lado en tu ejemplo que colocas primero debería quedar así

```js
async function getMain(){
  let message = 'Hola Mundo'
  const response = await (message)
  console.log(response)
}

getMain()//aquí mando ejecutar la función
```

Donde como puedes notar posterior a la declaración de la función con la keyword `async`, hago:

1. asigno a una variable message el valor de `"hola mundo"` que deseo imprimir
2. posterior a una constante la igualo con la variable `message` pero indicando que debe esperar por la resolución de este mismo con la
   keyword `await`
3. posterior imprimo el valor con ayuda de `console.log()`
4. Finalmente para que la función trabaje, solo la invoco por su nombre y una pareja de parentesis

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si necesitas comparar el mismo ejercicio pero desde la perspectiva del uso explicito de las *promises*, te dejo este ejemplo también funcional

```js
let message = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  let saludo = 'Hola Mundo'; 
  resolve(saludo)
})

message.then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error.message)
})
```

> Donde puedes notar que hasta el día de hoy tenemos tres estados de las
>   promesas: `resolve`, `pending` y `reject`

1. `Resolve`: es el momento que el flujo de código trabajó normal y se ejecutó la lógica contenida
2. `Pending`, no existe como tal un error en el código pero esta esperando para devolver el resultado de la promesa
3. `Rejected`: indica que se rechazó, sin embargo a diferencia de un trhow exception, no mata el flujo del código

> Con respecto a la última pregunta, si se puede dar el caso de
>   múltiples await dentro de otros; dejo un ejemplo que tengo con un
>   ejercicio en VueJS y me es funcional

```
getFotos: async function(){
        let data = await(await fetch("https://api.example.com/fotos")).json()
        this.datos = data
      }
```

Comment: entonces ya no es necesario usar new promise(function(rs,rj)) ? con async y await puedo sobrevivir?

Comment: si utilizas la sintáxis de async y await ya no es necesario puedes llevar a buen termino la resolción sin la declaración explicita de promises

Comment: el .then es suplido por await?

Comment: si es suplido por el await, await puede existir varias veces, un chaining de awaits?

Comment: por dentro cualquier función declarada como async  que dentro ejecute await retorna de manera implicita una promesa; al usar también await junto con async se vuelve innecesario usar then; lo cual se traduce en una sintáxis acortada y mas expresiva

Comment: puedes modificar mi codigo ? el .then esta por demas en mi codigo?